# Terminal on Mac not providing responses using various PID related commands

Tags: mac, terminal, port, sudo, pid

When I try and find the PID of a port using a command such as any of the following (where xxxx is the port number):

```
lsof -i tcp:xxxx
netstat -vanp --tcp | grep xxxx
sudo lsof -i -P | grep LISTEN | grep :xxxx
```

..I get no information - terminal just moves me onto the next line. I know it's doing something, as I get asked for a password after some commands, and if I attempt to close terminal it warns me that I will stop the grep process (after having initiated it).

But I don't get any PID info - no response such as 'PID is xxxx' or whatever. Just the same response as if I had just hit return. Nothing.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The third command (starting `sudo lsof`) should work (although it's inefficient). Are you sure there's really something listening on that TCP port on your system?

The first (`lsof` without `sudo`) will only be able to look at processes you own, so if there's a system/other user process listening on that port it won't list it. The second (`netstat`) uses a bunch of linux options that macOS's version of `netstat` won't understand (it really should give you an error message about this).

To get `lsof` to show what's listening on a particular TCP port, you can use its own options to limit the listing rather than piping the output through a bunch of `grep` commands. Here's an example shoring listeners on port 22 (the ssh service):

```
$ sudo lsof -iTCP:22 -sTCP:LISTEN  
Password:
COMMAND PID USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
launchd   1 root    8u  IPv6 0xaf9262dbf16046f7      0t0  TCP *:ssh (LISTEN)
launchd   1 root    9u  IPv4 0xaf9262dbf160ae7f      0t0  TCP *:ssh (LISTEN)
launchd   1 root   11u  IPv6 0xaf9262dbf16046f7      0t0  TCP *:ssh (LISTEN)
launchd   1 root   12u  IPv4 0xaf9262dbf160ae7f      0t0  TCP *:ssh (LISTEN)
```

Note that there's only one process listening (`launchd`, process ID 1), but it technically has 4 file descriptors attached to the port, so they're listed separately.

You can also use `netstat`. It doesn't need `sudo` to see other users' processes, but it'll only show the process ID, and you have to search the output for relevant entries. Here, I use `awk` instead of `grep`, so I can get it to show the column headers as well as the network listeners:

```
$ netstat -anv | awk '(NR<=2 || /[.]22.*LISTEN/)'
Active Internet connections (including servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q  Local Address          Foreign Address        (state)     rhiwat shiwat    pid   epid  state    options
tcp4       0      0  *.22                   *.*                    LISTEN      131072 131072      1      0 0x0180 0x00000006
tcp6       0      0  *.22                   *.*                    LISTEN      131072 131072      1      0 0x0180 0x00000006
```

Note the `pid` column, far off to the right side (it'll probably wrap around in a normal-sized Terminal window).